# Are [kthreadd] and [rcu_gp] commands?

Tags: init

I want to learn from the output from command ps

```
usr@host:~$ ps -ef | head -5 
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 16:43 ?        00:00:04 /sbin/init splash
root         2     0  0 16:43 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 16:43 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
root         4     2  0 16:43 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
```

`/sbin/init` is not hard to follow, utility `init` start a big bang to splash elements, it is a command.

when it comes to [kthreadd], [rcu_gp], I do not find such utilities or command from the entire file system.

Are they commands?

Comment: I believe those are bits inside the Linux Kernel, and not utilities or commands that are executed in userspace.

Comment: They are kernel processes, this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988526/ Or this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83322/